# How to perform a Prediction with Matlabs Hidden Markov Model? (Statistics Toolbox)

Tags: matlab, prediction, hidden-markov-models

I have trained a HMM in matlab using the [hmmtrain-function](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/stats/hmmtrain.html) from the statistics package.

Using [hmmdecode](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/stats/hmmdecode.html) and my given evidence between t_0 and t_1, I can do Filtering and Smoothing to compute the posterior distribution over the possible states between t_0 and t_1.

Now I want to compute the posterior distribution over a future state later than t_1, given all evidence to date. In theroy, this means I have to apply the forward-algorithm on the markov chain.

Do you know which matlab-function I can use to do this?  I suppose that there is something built-in in the statistics package, I just cannot find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the probability over hidden states at t_2, just multiply your posterior over t_1 by your transition matrix.

Comment: Thank you, I was looking for something built-in but they proabbly left it to the user. Is there a reason why I have to normalize? Shouldn't it be normalized already?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out the matlab statistics package is a bit scarce when it comes  to HMMs. [Kevin Murphy's toolbox](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~murphyk/Software/HMM/hmm.html) seems to offer much more functionality and a lot of convenience functions.